# Separate Rows and Columns of Matrix in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell and I'm having trouble figuring stuff out.
Let's say I have a Matrix and I want to separate said matrix into **rows** and **cols**. How would I do that?

```
-- set up
type Matrix m = [Row m]
type Row m = [m]

-- gets rows from matrix
rows :: Matrix m -> [Row m]
rows = ???

-- gets cols from matrix
cols :: Matrix m -> [Row m]
cols = ???
```

Comment: Your `Matrix m` type is already defined as `[Row m]`, so it's *already* represented as a list of rows (or columns, depending on how you think of it), you don't need to do anything there. For the other one, you can use the [transpose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) function.

Comment: Again, I am very much new. How should I use transpose? And if I did want to set rows to something even if it is already in row major, how would I do that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you check the examples in the documentation link I gave? In my opinion they make it perfectly clear what `transpose` does and how to use it. I'm afraid I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Would rows just be "rows = rows" (if I want to put something where rows was). and would cols be " cols  = transpose"? Again I'm still learning so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Well it would be `rows = id`, which is just the "do nothing" function. `id` exists in the standard library for a reason, but I really don't see how you need it here, you simply don't need a function at all.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: Devil’s advocate, if you wanted to define a module that hides its internal representation of matrices, you’d still export `rows` even if its implementation were trivial (and encapsulate `Matrix` as a `newtype` or `data` type instead of a `type` synonym, and so on)

Comment: @JonPurdy - fair point, but I think it's pretty clear that this isn't what's going on here, and mentioning such cases would probably just confuse the OP.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since Matrix m = [Row m] that means that it's already separated into rows

```
...
rows = id
```

For cols we can use transpose which works the same was tranpose works in Linear Algebra.

```
...
cols = transpose
```

Comment: `rows = rows` defines an infinite loop.  Maybe you mean `rows rs = rs` or `rows = id` (they are equivalent)